# CSS page layout, keep text in its own div column

Tags: html, css, layout

I have a page layout with two div. They are both float:left and so appear as columns next to each other. I want them to stay that way. However, if the text in the right-most div is too long then the whole text moves down below the left most column. This also happens if the text is short, but I make the browser window smaller. What I want is for the long text to take up more lines, but only within its own right column.

CSS:

```
.left{float:left}
.right{float:left}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class = "left">
         <span>some text</span>
    </div>
    <div class = "right">
        <span>some long text....</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Edit: Also, the left column should stay fixed.

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like you want to do something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/VV4Hc/8/

The outer container specifies the width those two divs should occupy. As you can see, they also have percentage widths so you can change the container's property without having to go back and change the divs.

Word of warning, remember to clear your floats as well, so other elements don't get "caught" in the float. To do that, just define an element with the property `clear:both` like this:

```
.container {
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 0px auto; /* This will center the container on the page. */
 }
.left, .right {
   float: left; 
   width: 50%;
}
.clearfix {clear:both;}

<div class="container">
  <div class="left">...</div>
  <div class="right">...</div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
  <p>I won't get caught.</p>
</div>
```

If you're looking to do this for layout, you may want to consider a CSS framework, which has these sorts of things perfectly measured based on a specified number of columns. See:

- [Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/)/[Kickstrap](http://getkickstrap.com)
- [960.gs](http://960.gs/)
- [Blueprint](http://www.blueprintcss.org/)

Comment: The first link is almost what I want. What I really want is like this very page that we are looking at: when the browser is made smaller, the menu on the right disappears, but the question/answer column does not change width. What I have would be the equivalent of the menu dropping down below the question/answers.

Comment: Oops, just found an error in my code. Please see the updated link. I've changed it in my answer.

Comment: Ah, it works now. But you mean to include float:left, right? The part I was missing was setting the container width. And then I also used fixed width for left and right.

Comment: (the text in the right-most column doesn't spread over more lines until the column gets so narrow that it disappears, but maybe that's too much to hope for. The cases where I have seen this, also affects the width of the left-most column.)

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you hope to accomplish when the window narrows? Earlier you were saying you just wanted the right menu to "disappear".

Comment: Yes, sorry. What I really want is for it to be like this very page, with the menu on the right. However, as the browser is made smaller, the menu words should go on to more lines without the left column changing. Once the browser is the width of the left column, the right disappears completely. Essentially the behavior of the two columns would be different. Since that may not be possible, I'll go with your example.

Comment: I figured out an answer and added it. Sorry if I wasn't clear in what I wanted.

Comment: You say no tables, but that is all that works for me. I need the left column to stay unchanged and the right column to squeeze the text in. (The left column contains things like a calendar, which must not be "mutated". The right column contains text that can be squeezed to fit the window)

Comment: You need only define a width, in pixels for the left column and it will not mutate.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the positions for those divs like

```
.left{width: 50%; position:relative; top:0%; left:0%;}
.right{width: 50%; position:relative; top:0%; left:50%;}
```

Comment: Why the `top` and `left` properties if it's relatively positioned?

Comment: Because the divs wants a relation with the outer div.

Comment: Perhaps you meant to position it with absolute?

Answer (score -2):

I was able to solve it with a table. When the window is made smaller, at first only the right column is made smaller and the words squeeze down on more lines until the column has disappeared. If the browser is made smaller than the width of the left column, then the left column starts disappearing, cutting off words. Works in my Chrome and IE although I don't know about older IE.

```
.td_right{vertical-align:top; max-width:300px;}
.td_left{vertical-align:top; min-width:300px; width:300}

<table >
    <tr> 
        <td class = "td_left">
            stuff here
        </td> 
        <td class = "td_right">
            stuff here 
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: No!!!! Don't use tables for layout! http://webdesign.about.com/od/layout/a/aa111102a.htm